# How to exit scanf loop when there is a space

Tags: c

For example, the user shall put the input like that, "ABC123," but not "ABC 123" or "A BC123."

Here is my code:

```
unsigned int convert_to_num(char * string) {
unsigned result = 0;
char ch;
//printf("check this one %s\n", string);
while(ch =*string++) result = result * 26 + ch - 'A' + 1;
return result;
}


int main()
{
char input_string[100];
char arr_col[100] = {'\0'};
char arr_row[100] = {'\0'};
int raiseflag;
int started_w_alpha =0;
int digitflag = 0;
while(scanf("%s", &input_string) != EOF) {

int i = 0, j = 0, digarr = 0;

while (i <=5) {
if (input_string[i] == '\0') {printf("space found!");}
if ((input_string[i] >= 'A' && input_string[i] <= 'Z') && (digitflag == 0)) {
started_w_alpha = 1;
arr_col[j] = input_string[i]; j++;
}
//printf("something wrong here %s and %d and j %d\n", arr_holder, i, j);
if (started_w_alpha == 1) {

    if (input_string[i] >=48 && input_string[i]<=57){ digitflag = 1; arr_row[digarr] =input_string[i]; digarr++; }
}

i++; if (i == 5) { raiseflag =1; }

}

printf(" => [%d,%s]\n", convert_to_num(arr_col), arr_row);
if (raiseflag == 1) { raiseflag = 0; memset(arr_col, 0, 5); memset(input_string, 0, 5); memset(arr_row, 0, 5); digitflag = 0; started_w_alpha = 0; }

 }
    return 0;

}
```

Apparently, \0 doesn't work in my case because I have an array of 5 and user can put 2 chars. I want to exit the loop whenever a space is found in between the characters.

This is the whole code. I added {'\0'} my array because of the extra characters I get when there is less than 5 characters.
Thanks!

Comment: Your buffer isn't big enough, and you need to do `== 1` instead of `!= EOF`

Comment: @MattMcNabb thanks matt! I will update that.

Comment: in `if (input_string[i] == '\0')` the `'\0'` means end of string, if you find it you should break the loop.

Comment: @SHR That's not what I'm looking for. When I try "ABC12" I still get that there is a space. And I only want to exit the loop when it is something like "AB C23" "A C" etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the index is starting from 0 and `input_string[5];` array size is 5, the only valid indexes are from 0 to 4.

but your loop `while (i <=5) {` go till 5, it is mean you exceed the array.

If you insert 5 characters to the string, the terminating null is the 6th.

Since you exceed the array it written over some other variable. but you still can find it when you check `input_string[5]`

So if you want to insert 5 characters you array size should be at least 6

`char input_string[6];`

if you want to check only the first 5 elements you'll have to change the loop to:

`while (i < 5) {`

and as I wrote in the comment if you find the terminating null, no use to continue the loop, since it contain garbage or leftover from the previous iteration.

Therefor you should break if it found, like this:

`if (input_string[i] == '\0') {printf("space found!"); break;}`

**EDIT**
check this program: it use `fgets` to read the whole input, then search for white spaces.

Note it doesn't trim the input, means it won't remove spaces when thay appear at the beginning or at the end of the input.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i ,size;
    char input_string[100];
    fgets(input_string,100,stdin);
    i=0;
    size = strlen(input_string);
    while (i<size-1){ //enter is also count 
      if (isspace(input_string[i])) 
      {
          printf("space found!");
          break;
      }
      i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT2**

Now with a trim, so it will remove leading and ending spaces:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* trim(char *input_string)
{
  int i=0;
  char *retVal = input_string;
  i = strlen(input_string)-1;
  while( i>=0 && isspace(input_string[i]) ){
      input_string[i] = 0;
      i--;
  }

  i=0;
  while(*retVal && isspace(retVal[0]) ){
    retVal ++;
  }
  return retVal;
}

int main()
{
    int i ,size;
    char input_string[100],*ptr;
    fgets(input_string,100,stdin);
    ptr = trim(input_string);
    i=0;
    size = strlen(ptr);

    while (i<size){
      if (isspace(ptr[i])) 
      {
          printf("space found!");
          break;
      }
      i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I fixed that but still not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just change the array size to 6, and check only 5, or till the terminating null. but still there is always terminating null at the end of the string, so something is wrong with your algorithm.

Comment: That's what I did but it keeps exiting the loop even if there is no white space. For example, if I entered, "AB12," it exits. and I want it to continue looping as long as there is nothing like "AB 12 or A B12"

Comment: in the `input_string= "AB12"` there is terminating null in `input_string[4]`. `scanf` anyway read only until the white space.

Comment: I changed it to 100. I was just testing things but I don't know how many chars the user will put but they will not exceed 100. Again now I'm lost with how to exits if there is a space between the characters. Can i use it under the scanf loop? I tried it under scanf loop but it is not working either. if (input_string == '\0') sorry im new with C and I'm lost.

Comment: See the edit in the answer, hope it will help. note the change.

Comment: Appreciate your help, but I tried your function and it gives space found even when there is no space. Try "ABC"

Comment: In EDIT2: 1) `i = strlen(input_string)-1;`, the -1 is not needed.  Should `input_stirng` end with a `'\n'`, the rest of code will trim it. 2) `input_string` might not end with a `'\n'` and so `strlen(input_string)-1` starts in the wrong spot.

Comment: the `strlen` give you the index of the terminating null, maybe it work without the -1, but no use to write 0 when it is 0.